# How to search a tree folder

Tags: unix, find, tree

How can I do a search of all directories calles `i18n` under trees like `src/main/resources` using find or any other unix command.

Everything I'm trying doesn't work

I'm looking for something like:

```
$find . -name 'src/main/resources/i18n/ -type d
./foo/src/main/resources/i18n/
./bar/src/main/resources/i18n/
./xyz/src/main/resources/i18n/
```

But directory './foo/src/test/resources/i18n' should not appear.

Comment: "everything I'm trying" is not very useful. What *have* you tried?

Comment: I've already found the correct option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it at last:

```
find -type d -regex ".*src/main/resources/i18n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Specify the common root dir of all your trees instead of `.`

```
find common/root/dir/ -type d -name i18n
```

(You can specify an absolute path there of course.)

Comment: This isn't working

Comment: Could you be more specific about that?

Comment: $ find src/main/resources/ -type d -name i18n
find: src/main/resources/: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah, yes. I slightly misunderstood your question. See my edit, in your case the common root seems to be `.` but you need to use only "i18n" with -name, not the rest of the paths as well.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that, but that gives me both the 'src/main/resources/i18n' and the 'src/test/resources/i18n' that I don't need.

Comment: That was not in the question either. In that case I think your own solution might be best.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should edit the question